# WCF Enum issue: cannot "or" the enum values

Tags: wcf, enums

I use enum as flags and wants to "or" it, but always meet a error:

Enum value '3' is invalid for type 'Common.EventType' and cannot be serialized. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute

code:

```
[DataContract]
public enum EventType
{
    [EnumMember]
    Event1 = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Event2 = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    Event3 = 4,
    [EnumMember]
    AllEvents = Event1 | Event2 | Event3
}
```

MyContractClient proxy = new MyContractClient(context);

proxy.Subscribe(**EventType.Event1 | EventType.Event2**);

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add the [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) to use bitwise operations (`&` and `|`) on enum types. Although, I am not sure if this will correct the given error ..

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the [Flags] attribute to send flags over WCF.

[Enumeration Types in Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx)

```
[DataContract][Flags]
public enum EventType
{
  [EnumMember]
  Event1 = 1,
  [EnumMember]
  Event2 = 2,
  [EnumMember]
  Event3 = 4,
  [EnumMember]
  AllEvents = Event1 | Event2 | Event3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I had this issue:

```
... and cannot be serialized. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present 
and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has 
DataContractAttribute attribute
```

I found I was accidentally sending the Enum over the WCF proxy as an **int** instead of the actual enum value.

In my case

```
bad: request.MyEnum = 1
good: request.MyEnum = MyActualEnum.Number1
```